# submit form in QML

Tags: qml

i'd like to do this:
show some form, handle Rectangle::onClicked  event (disable form, set opacity to 0.2, process some javascript to submit form, then set opacity back to 1.0, enable form).
But I don't know how to do it.

It seems onClicked() is processed in "batch" mode, changing any ui properties aren't visible until the function exits. I played with states, transitions and animations, but still not succeed.

Thanks for any suggestion,
Michal

Answer (score 2):

You can simply start two custom animations, one to hide the form and one to show it back. Something like this:

```
SequentialAnimation {
  id: submitAndHideForm

  ParallelAnimation {
    // Animations to hide the form elements
  }
  ScriptAction {
    script: submitForm()
  }
}

ParallelAnimation {
  id: showForm

  // Animations to show the form elements
}
```

Then you could just start the first one with `submitAndHideForm.start()` when you want to submit the form, and when you get a response you can start the second one.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to solve with states. You could try to do the Javascript processing in a [WorkerScript](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-workerscript.html). When the processing is done it will send back a reply to the QML WorkerScript element that sets the state of the form to enabled again. So in onClicked you do the disable animation by setting the state, and in the onMessage function of the WorkerScript element you do the enable animation by setting the state to "enabled".

Comment: This solution looks fine, except script function has no access to context. Is there any way, how to pass any object into function? There is "network" variable which is python object (via context property). I tried to pass it this way: saveScript.sendMessage({'network': network}) but it doesn't work for me. When I call message.network.save() inside function, I got exception: TypeError: Result of expression 'message.network' [null] is not an object.

Comment: According Restrictions section, I couldn't use it because I need to access "context properties set on the QML object through QDeclarativeContex"

Comment: And something similar was discussed here: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?228097-How-is-the-context-of-WorkerScript-defined

Comment: Great! Yes, it is indeed ugly.. :) There must be a cleaner solution, perhaps the one suggested by TheHuge_ works better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you talking about using `XMLHttpRequest` asynchronously. "Disable" form on sending request, and "enable" it when `onreadystatechange` called with `readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE`.

Comment: No, my question is focused to changing UI elements in QML (enable/disabling). In my code, "submitting" is done by calling python function (via context property)